# Node.js call functions within a function as callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, asynchronous, callback

So, I'd like to have the following construct:

```
var _class = function() {};

_class.prototype.checkThis = function(callback) {
    console.log('this');
};

_class.prototype.checkThat = function(callback){
    console.log('that');
};

_class.prototype.validate = function(callback){
    var self = this;
    this.checkThis(function(err) {
        if(!err) self.checkThat(callback);
    });
}

var inst = new _class;

inst.validate();
```

Unfortunately, "this" does not point to the "class" within the callback of "checkThis" such that "checkThat" is unknown.
Any ideas?

Comment: Is `class` a function? It should be, because otherwise `.prototype` does not work.

Comment: `class` is a reserved keyword. Please use a different identifier.

Comment: no, thats why "class" :D

Comment: You know you're missing curlybraces as well as using reserved keywords, as pointed out by Bergi? Here -> http://jsfiddle.net/k5wYX/1/

Comment: Sorry, for the bad question. I fixed it, thanks!